# parsing a complex filter definition with pyparsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

I am trying to parse a complex filter definition that will be applied on a set of data. A typical filter could look like this :

```
attribute1 == value1 and (attribute2 >= 3 or attribute3 != value3)
```

Of course, the filtering can be much more complex using more nested levels and logical operators. What it all boils down to is :

1. Extracting the "unit filtering expressions" such as `attribute1 == value1`
2. Run each filter in the set of data
3. Combine results using intersections (and) and unions (or)

I heavily reused some examples already provided by Paul McGuire, so my code looks like this :

```
import pyparsing

def process_results(result):
    for key in result.keys():
        print(key + ":" + str(result[key]))
        if key == 'complex_filter':
            process_results(result[key])


def parse_filter(filter_string):
    # break these up so we can represent higher precedence for 'and' over 'or'
    not_operator        = pyparsing.oneOf(['not','^'], caseless=True).setResultsName("operator")
    and_operator        = pyparsing.oneOf(['and','&'], caseless=True).setResultsName("operator")
    or_operator         = pyparsing.oneOf(['or' ,'|'], caseless=True).setResultsName("operator")

    # db_keyword is okay, but you might just want to use a general 'identifier' expression,
    # you won't have to keep updating as you add other terms to your query language
    ident = pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.alphas+'_'+'-', pyparsing.alphanums+'_'+'-')

    # comparison operators
    comparison_operator = pyparsing.oneOf(['==','!=','>','>=','<', '<='])

    # instead of generic 'value', define specific value types
    integer = pyparsing.Regex(r'[+-]?\d+').setParseAction(lambda t:int(t[0]))
    float_ = pyparsing.Regex(r'[+-]?\d+\.\d*').setParseAction(lambda t:float(t[0]))

    # use pyparsing's QuotedString class for this, it gives you quote escaping, and
    # automatically strips quotes from the parsed text
    quote = pyparsing.QuotedString('"')

    # when you are doing boolean expressions, it's always handy to add TRUE and FALSE literals
    literal_true = pyparsing.Keyword('true', caseless=True)
    literal_false = pyparsing.Keyword('false', caseless=True)
    boolean_literal = literal_true | literal_false

    # in future, you can expand comparison_operand to be its own operatorPrecedence
    # term, so that you can do things like "nucleon != 1+2" - but this is fine for now
    comparison_operand = quote | ident | float_ | integer
    comparison_expr = pyparsing.Group((quote | ident) + comparison_operator + comparison_operand).setResultsName("unit_filter", listAllMatches=True )


    grammar = pyparsing.infixNotation(comparison_expr,
        [
        (not_operator, 1, pyparsing.opAssoc.RIGHT),
        (and_operator, 2, pyparsing.opAssoc.LEFT),
        (or_operator,  2, pyparsing.opAssoc.LEFT),
        ]
    ).setResultsName("complex_filter")

    res = grammar.parseString(filter_string, parseAll=True)

    return res

res = parse_filter('attribute1 == value1 and (attribute2 >= 3 or attribute3 != value3)')

process_results(res)
```

The output is quite close to what I would like :

```
complex_filter:[['attribute1', '==', 'value1'], 'and', [['attribute2', '>=', 3], 'or', ['attribute3', '!=', 'value3']]]
unit_filter:[['attribute1', '==', 'value1']]
operator:and
```

As you can see, it won't keep looping through the "nested" results... I would like the output to be

```
complex_filter:[['attribute1', '==', 'value1'], 'and', [['attribute2', '>=', 3], 'or', ['attribute3', '!=', 'value3']]]
unit_filter:[['attribute1', '==', 'value1']]
operator:and
complex_filter: [['attribute2', '>=', 3], 'or', ['attribute3', '!=', 'value3']]
unit_filter:[['attribute2', '>=', 3]]
operator:or
unit_filter:[['attribute3', '!=', 'value3']]
```

Any idea of what I could do to get there ? Thanks !

Comment: Rather than base your evaluation strategy on results names, try using classes that model each level of the operator precedence. You can see an example of this in the SimpleBool.py parser on the pyparsing wiki examples page. With appropriate repr or str methods on the classes, you should be able to get the output you want.